# ReactiveUI and WithLatestFrom

Tags: wpf, reactiveui, rx.net

I've just started looking into ReactiveUI and I guess I'm missing something. Say I have a 'Connect' button and want to create a new network connection based on the server address in a TextBox. I thought, I'd create a ReactiveCommand and bind it to the Button, then do something like WithLatestFrom with the value of the server address property (that's how I've done it in Java or Typescript).
However I can't find the right syntax. Can anyone elaborate?
BR,
Daniel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The adrian answer is fine, I'll add some code to help a little bit more:

```
public class MainViewModel : ReactiveObject
{
    private string connectionUrl;

    // constructor
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        // maybe you need to disable the button if the textbox is empty
       // ypu can create an observable to check if ConnectionUrl is null or empty
       var canConnect = this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.ConnectionUrl)
           .Where(conn => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(conn);

        // use "ReactiveCommand.CreateFromTask" if you need asynchronous operations.
        ConnectCommand = ReactiveCommand.Create(() =>
        {
             // you can use the ConnectionUrl property here, for example
            var dbConnection = new DbConnection(ConnectionUrl);
        }, canConnect); // <-- we are telling to the command when will be enabled
    }

    // this property will be binded to the textbox
    public string ConnectionUrl
    {
        get => connectionUrl;
        set => this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref connectionUrl, value);
    }

    // this command will be binded to the button
    public ReactiveCommand ConnectCommand { get; }
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Ok my friend, if I understood you should do something like this:

First your ViewModel, you want to derive from ReactiveObject in order to get access to **this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(...)** wichs triggers **INotifyPropertyChanged**

```
public class MainViewModel : ReactiveObject
{
    private string _connectionUrl;

    public string ConnectionUrl
    {
        get => _connectionUrl;
        set => this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _connectionUrl, value);
    }

    public ReactiveCommand ConnectCommand { get; set; }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        ConnectCommand = ReactiveCommand.Create(() =>
        {
            //your logic goes here...
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Button Pressed");
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"{ConnectionUrl}");
        });
    }
}
```

Next thing to do is wire your View and your ViewModel via view's **DataContext**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.DataContext = new MainViewModel();
    }
}
```

And of course the required XAML to bind controls to properties and commands

```
<Window x:Class="WPFRx.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPFRx"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
            VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <TextBox x:Name="Connection"
             Text="{Binding ConnectionUrl, Mode=TwoWay}"
             VerticalAlignment="Center"
             HorizontalAlignment="Center"
             Width="200"/>
    <Button x:Name="BtnConnect"
            Content="Connect"
            Command="{Binding ConnectCommand}"/>

</StackPanel>
</Window>
```

I hope this helps you, regards.

Comment: this helped you ?

Comment: Maybe Im wrong but I think this line: "public ReactiveCommand ConnectCommand { get; set; }" should be "public ReactiveCommand<Unit, Unit> ConnectCommand { get; }". You dont want to expose the ReactiveCommand as a "read/write" property, it is better to declare as readonly property.

Comment: Good one, you are right. It would be better as readonly property, also the reactiveui band recommends _ReactiveCommand<Unit,Unit>_